# Infinite loop linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, structure, infinite-loop

It seems right here in my code I have an infinite loop of printing out the same class_t variable called search, despite trying to move the variable forward to the next class_t. All class_t structures either point towards (class_t*)0 (because I got compiler warnings if I used NULL because I was comparing class_t* and void*), or point to the next appropriate class_t structure. What am I doing wrong, or should I be looking somewhere else for my problem?

```
class_t *search = (students + i)->class_p;//students is a seperate structure where class_p is a pointer to a class_t structure
            while(search != (class_t*)0)
            {
                    fprintf(output,": %s%d %d %d\n", search->name, search->number, search->section, search->credits);
                    search = search->nextClass;
            }
```

Here's a sample of the output, and looking at it, it's the last read in class_t from the file

```
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
: CS521 1 4
```

And here's the class_t creation:

```
    class_t newClass;
newClass.number = classid;
newClass.section = section;
newClass.credits = credits;
newClass.nextClass = (class_t*)0;
```

And when the node is added:

```
void addNode(student_t students[], class_t addClass, int ref)
{
int found = 0;

if((students + ref)->class_p == (class_t*)0)//no classes yet
{
    (students + ref)->class_p = &addClass;
    found = 1;
}
else if((*((students + ref)->class_p)).number > addClass.number && found == 0)//checks first class
{
    class_t *temp = (students + ref)->class_p;
    (students + ref)->class_p = &addClass;
    addClass.nextClass = temp;
    found = 1;
}
else//works way through the class linked list to find where it goes
{
    class_t *beforesearch = (students + ref)->class_p;
    class_t *search = beforesearch->nextClass;
    while(search != (class_t*)0 && found == 0)
    {
        if(search->number < addClass.number)
        {
            beforesearch->nextClass = &addClass;
            addClass.nextClass = search;
            found = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            beforesearch = search;
            search = search->nextClass;
        }
    }

    if(found == 0)
    {
        beforesearch->nextClass = &addClass;
        found = 1;
    }
}
```

}

Header files with typedefs:

```
typedef struct class_t {
char name[3];
int number;
int section;
int credits;
struct class_t *nextClass;
} class_t;

typedef struct student_t {
int id;
class_t *class_p;
} student_t;
```

Comment: I'd evaluate how you're handling your head/tail when adding/remove nodes. It's likely you're introducing a cycle.

Comment: Need to see how you constructed the list. There is a loop in it!

Comment: Please add an output sample, so we can see if there is a pattern - if Slaks is correct - it will probably be shown in the output sample.

Comment: What kind of complaints did you get when you used NULL? Complaints from the compiler or from your supervisor?

Comment: You might want to lookup ["The Tortoise and the Hare"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TortoiseAndHare).

Comment: in AddNode(), you are taking the addres of addclass(which is a function argument) , and assigning it to a ->nectClass pointer. NOTE: this is not *the* offending error, but it looks wrong to me.

Comment: @wildplasser Changed it to use a pointer to the original struct rather than using the copy in the argument, get the same loop.

Comment: As I said, *this is not the offending error*, there are more. Also the type definitions for student_t and class_t are missing. (and you have a *very strange* style of array indexing/ponter dereferencing, which makes the code hard to read, at least for me.)

Comment: @wildplasser The array indexing pointer referencing is a professor's preference, sorry. The typedef is in my header files, but I'll throw them up there if you want a look

Comment: I added a homework-tag to satisfy the offending professor. Maybe he should post here himself (or does he have didactic strategies) ?

Comment: @wildplasser I'm trying to get a hold of said professor, but he tends to be "out" pretty often :P And he doesn't have a whole lot for strategies in general.

Comment: Why don't you print the address of the node too? Just in case it is not a node pointing to itself, but a closed chain or cycle

Answer (score 1):

It is a very subtle error:

```
void addNode(student_t students[], class_t addClass, int ref)
{
    int found = 0;

    if((students + ref)->class_p == (class_t*)0)//no classes yet
    {
        (students + ref)->class_p = &addClass;
```

You are passing `addClass` by value (i.e. a whole copy of the struct I presume) and then using its address to link it in the list.  This is wrong as you are using **the address of a function parameter** which belongs to the call stack.

If you're getting a list loop means you've hit the case in which each call to `addNode` copies the struct to the same address in the stack.  But this is a lot of luck, there are **so many things** that can go wrong with this code that I won't explain them all.

The proper solution is to allocate `class_t` nodes on the heap (i.e. with `malloc()`) and pass a pointer to them.  Or else allocate a copy before linking:

```
void addNode(student_t students[], class_t addClass_param, int ref)
{
    class_t *addClass = malloc(sizeof(class_t)); /* Check for NULL return skipped */
    memcpy(addClass, &addClass_param, sizeof(class_t));
    /* ... */
```

Comment: I took your suggestion, but it made no difference. I gave it room on the heap as well as made sure everything was copied over to the new spot. However, it now prints nothing to the output file and is still stuck in some sort of loop.

Comment: @Setzra: This is the kind of situation where a debugger comes handy.